# Construction of Casimir invariants

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra and $ad$ be its adjoint representation. For each $Z \in \mathfrak{g}$, we can associate it with the characteristic polynomial
$$
f_{Z}(\lambda) = \det(\lambda - ad(Z)) = \sum_{j=0}^n  \phi_{j}(Z) \lambda^{n-j},
$$
where $\phi_j(Z)$ are homogeneous polynomials in $Z$ of degree $j$. If we let $X_i, 1 \leq i \leq n$ be a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$, then $Z = \sum_i z_iX_i$, and $\phi_j$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $z_i$'s.

I saw a claim in the book Lie groups, physics and geometry that if we replace the indeterminate $z_i$'s of $\phi_j$ by $X_i$'s, then $\phi_j(X)$ is a Casimir invariant of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\phi_j(X)$ commutes with all elements of $\mathfrak{g}$.

How do we prove this fact?

Comment: I don't think the author's claim is fully true (or I might have some misunderstanding). I checked the claim for the two dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra and it does not work. However, there seems many examples that this construction works.

Comment: Have you checked the case of $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}_2$?

Comment: Yes, I checked the case when $n=2$ and $n=3$. I think we should take the order into account when computing the determinant.